# paypal IPN doesnt add data to the mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

The paypal IPN doesn't enter the data into the mysql database for some reason!!
I am using paypal sandbox and the payments go through and they show in my sandbox account but the details wont show in the mysql!!

this is my IPN file. although I called it payments.php and I also used the IPN simulator to point to it and it did it said the IPN sent succesfully. So I don't know what the issue is here:

```
<?php
// Database variables
$host = "localhost"; //database location
$user = "my details"; //database username
$pass = "pass"; //database password
$db_name = "my details"; //database name

// PayPal settings
$paypal_email = 'MYSANDBOXEMAIL@PAYPAL.COM';
$return_url = 'http://some site/';
$cancel_url = 'http://some site/';
$notify_url = 'http://some site/thanks.php';

$item_name = 'Test Item';
$item_amount = 5.00;

// Include Functions
include("functions.php");

//Database Connection
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name);

// Check if paypal request or response
if (!isset($_POST["txn_id"]) && !isset($_POST["txn_type"])){

    // Firstly Append paypal account to querystring
    $querystring .= "?business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";  

    // Append amount& currency (£) to quersytring so it cannot be edited in html

    //The item name and amount can be brought in dynamically by querying the $_POST['item_number'] variable.
    $querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($item_name)."&";
    $querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($item_amount)."&";

    //loop for posted values and append to querystring
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $querystring .= "$key=$value&";
    }

    // Append paypal return addresses
    $querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);

    // Append querystring with custom field
    //$querystring .= "&custom=".USERID;

    // Redirect to paypal IPN
    header('location:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
    exit();

}else{

    // Response from Paypal

    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $data['item_name']          = $_POST['item_name'];
    $data['item_number']        = $_POST['item_number'];
    $data['payment_status']     = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $data['payment_amount']     = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $data['payment_currency']   = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $data['txn_id']             = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $data['receiver_email']     = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $data['payer_email']        = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $data['custom']             = $_POST['custom'];

    // post back to PayPal system to validate
    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30); 

    if (!$fp) {
        // HTTP ERROR
    } else {    

        fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
            if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

                // Used for debugging
                //@mail("you@youremail.com", "PAYPAL DEBUGGING", "Verified Response<br />data = <pre>".print_r($post, true)."</pre>");

                // Validate payment (Check unique txnid & correct price)
                $valid_txnid = check_txnid($data['txn_id']);
                $valid_price = check_price($data['payment_amount'], $data['item_number']);
                // PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!
                if($valid_txnid && $valid_price){               
                    $orderid = updatePayments($data);       
                    if($orderid){                   
                        // Payment has been made & successfully inserted into the Database                              
                    }else{                              
                        // Error inserting into DB
                        // E-mail admin or alert user
                    }
                }else{                  
                    // Payment made but data has been changed
                    // E-mail admin or alert user
                }                       

            }else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

                // PAYMENT INVALID & INVESTIGATE MANUALY! 
                // E-mail admin or alert user

                // Used for debugging
                //@mail("you@youremail.com", "PAYPAL DEBUGGING", "Invalid Response<br />data = <pre>".print_r($post, true)."</pre>");
            }       
        }       
    fclose ($fp);
    }   
}
?>
```

**Updated: Here is the function.php.. i hope this helps someone to help me resolve this!**

```
<?php
// functions.php
function check_txnid($tnxid){
    global $link;
    return true;
    $valid_txnid = true;
    //get result set
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM payments WHERE txnid = '$tnxid'", $link);     
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $valid_txnid = false;
    }
    return $valid_txnid;
}

function check_price($price, $id){
    $valid_price = false;
    //you could use the below to check whether the correct price has been paid for the product

    /* 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT amount FROM `products` WHERE id = '$id'");       
    if (mysql_numrows($sql) != 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $num = (float)$row['amount'];
            if($num == $price){
                $valid_price = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return $valid_price;
    */
    return true;
}

function updatePayments($data){ 
    global $link;
    if(is_array($data)){                
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO payments (txnid, payment_amount, payment_status, itemid, createdtime) VALUES (
                '".$data['txn_id']."' ,
                '".$data['payment_amount']."' ,
                '".$data['payment_status']."' ,
                '".$data['item_number']."' ,
                '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' 
                )", $link);
    return mysql_insert_id($link);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, we don't want to fix your BIG php file. Tell us the error you get first.

Comment: What are the contents of the updatePayments function? Is the updatePayments function ever called?

Comment: @j0k, I didn't think it was a "BIG" php file to be honest. especially for someone who knows what they are doing. and No, I don't get any error at all. No errors but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @beanland, Yes, I have updated the code and added the code for function.php as well. The updatePayment is called in function.php file. any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever resolve this, OP?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Print`ing or `echo`ing these values replacing -   `// Payment has been made & successfully inserted into the Database`

`print $data['item_name'];
 print $data['item_number'];.......`

And from there I could update till where it is correct and from where it is wrong.

Comment: Thank you but that didn't help. still not working. I mean the payments go through as they should but the database still not getting updated by paypal IPNs!!!

Comment: Thanks again, I added the $data = array(); and when I used the IPN simulator in my sandbox account, I got this error in paypal: IPN delivery failed. HTTP error code 404: Not Found.

Comment: Ok try the last update I have provided and remove the `$data = array();`

Comment: okay, I've tried all the options you've mentioned and still doesn't work!! I am at my wits end now with this paypal IPN thing. nothing works. I don't know what to do!!!

Comment: Hi there, it's Tim from PayPal. You could do something like a var_export and mail yourself the whole IPN post. Then you're able to check which data gets through and which not.

Comment: @TimMesserschmidt, Hi, Thank you for the inpute. any chance you could explain further please?

Comment: Do values of the above items get displayed?

Comment: Hi @user2056633 - did you try to receive the IPN's values somehow? For headless scripts (as the others already said) it's very convenient to use PHP's mail function for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are working a bit 'blind' because this is a 'headless' script and you don't know where it is failing.

Add some error_log lines at various points so that you can check the flow through the script. In particular, adding error_log($sql) just before you execute the DB query will print the statement to the error log. Take this and try to run it independently in the DB. It could be that some table constraints are failing rather than being an error in the PHP

Adding log lines at various points through the flow and printing out variables at those points will also help you diagnose where failure is happening and hopefully let you pinpoint the error more precisely.

Comment: I followed this tutorial for this purpose and apparently it worked for everybody else.. so why not me :( I have been working on this for 18 hours without sleep and food. I just can't understand why this is happening. tutorial is located here: http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration